# Associating models in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails so I'm still trying to figure things out so any help is greatly appreciated! I am building an app that will define "seasons" and there will be multiple "danceclasses" associated with those seasons. After you create a season, you should have the option to create "danceclasses" so as part of my show on the seasons I have:

```
<h2>Dance Classes Created</h2>
<%= @seasons.danceclass.each do |danceclass| %>
<p>
```

However I get the following error:

```
undefined method `danceclass' for nil:NilClass
```

My data model is I have a seasons table, a danceclasses table and a season_danceclasses table.

My model for seasons is this:

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :season_class
    has_many :danceclass, through: :season_class
end
```

My model for dance classes looks like this:

```
class Danceclass < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :season
    has_many :student_class
    has_many :student, through: :student_class
end
```

And my model for season_danceclass looks like this:

```
class SeasonDanceclasses < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :season 
    belongs_to :danceclass
end
```

My season_controller looks like this:

```
class SeasonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_season, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /seasons
  # GET /seasons.json
  def index
    @seasons = Season.all
  end

  # GET /seasons/1
  # GET /seasons/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /seasons/new
  def new
    @season = Season.new
  end

  # GET /seasons/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /seasons
  # POST /seasons.json
  def create
    @season = Season.new(season_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @season.save
        format.html { redirect_to @season, notice: 'Season was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @season }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @season.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /seasons/1
  # PATCH/PUT /seasons/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @season.update(season_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @season, notice: 'Season was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @season }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @season.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /seasons/1
  # DELETE /seasons/1.json
  def destroy
    @season.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to seasons_url, notice: 'Season was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_season
      @season = Season.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def season_params
      params.require(:season).permit(:season_name, :season_start, :season_end)
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Adding Schema.rb

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160729111417) do

  create_table "danceclasses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "class_id",          limit: 255
    t.string   "class_name",        limit: 255
    t.text     "class_description", limit: 65535
    t.integer  "min_students",      limit: 4
    t.integer  "max_students",      limit: 4
    t.string   "category",          limit: 255
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.integer  "week_frequency",    limit: 4
    t.integer  "day_frequency",     limit: 4
    t.string   "start_time",        limit: 255
    t.string   "end_time",          limit: 255
    t.integer  "fee",               limit: 4
    t.string   "level",             limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
  end

  create_table "season_classes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "season_id",     limit: 4
    t.integer "danceclass_id", limit: 4
  end

  create_table "seasons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "season_name",  limit: 255
    t.datetime "season_start"
    t.datetime "season_end"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
  end

  create_table "student_classes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "student_id", limit: 4
    t.integer "class_id",   limit: 4
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",    limit: 255
    t.string   "last_name",     limit: 255
    t.string   "student_id",    limit: 255
    t.datetime "date_of_birth"
    t.text     "notes",         limit: 65535
    t.string   "gender",        limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end

  create_table "user_students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id",    limit: 4
    t.integer "student_id", limit: 4
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username",      limit: 255
    t.string   "email",         limit: 255
    t.string   "password",      limit: 255
    t.string   "first_name",    limit: 255
    t.string   "last_name",     limit: 255
    t.string   "phone_number",  limit: 255
    t.datetime "date_of_birth"
    t.string   "street_1",      limit: 255
    t.string   "street_2",      limit: 255
    t.string   "city",          limit: 255
    t.string   "state",         limit: 255
    t.string   "zipcode",       limit: 255
    t.boolean  "enabled"
    t.boolean  "is_admin"
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you please share your schema.rb ? By the way, you should use pluralized name when declaring a has_many association.

Comment: It got error.. because @seasons contain more than 1 record.. so, you can only get the 1 season's many danceclasses.. it will be in inner loop .

Comment: You can do like this <% @seasons.each do |season| %> <%=  season.danceclasses.each do |danceclass| %><%end%><%end%>

Comment: @Blogger11 and yes.. its all also important to.. use plural in has_many association like this class                                                                   Season < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :season_classes
    has_many :danceclasses, through: :season_class
end

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `has_many` association properly.

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :season_classes
    has_many :danceclasses, through: :season_class
end
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the **associations you have taken should be plural for has_many**,

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :season_classes
    has_many :dance_classes, through: :season_classes
end


class Danceclass < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :season
    has_many :student_classes
    has_many :students, through: :student_classes
end

class SeasonDanceclasses < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :season 
    belongs_to :danceclass
end
```

Now, as you said that view is show page for season your season show action is,

```
class SeasonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_season, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @seasons = Season.all
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

Your show method contains **`@season` variable but not `@seasons`**, which was set in `set_season` action,

`so app/views/seasons/show.html.erb is,`

This is with your old association

```
<h2>Dance Classes Created</h2>
<% @season.danceclass.each do |danceclass| %> 
-----------
----------
<% end %>
<p></p>
```

This is with changed associations

```
<h2>Dance Classes Created</h2>
<% @season.dance_classes.each do |danceclass| %> 
-----------
----------
<% end %>
<p></p>
```